# Open local JSON file for examination

Tags: json, paw-app, paw

I was wondering if it's possible to open a local JSON file so I can just check its structure? Didn't/don't want to upload the file to an online JSON format checker site and was hoping I can just utilize PAW to do that.

Don't seem to be able to do this with a local file, unless I run it through a local server, eg using MAMP, unless I missed something...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the content into the txt body then switch to the JSON body this will let you view it in the nice structure, sorry currently no way to directly import a file need to copy past the content.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jsonlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) npm module. Supports JSON schema validation and pretty printing.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's one idea. But was hoping a robust app like PAW could do something like that. Worst case, I'll just stick to running a local server.